# What can I do to help my mouse be more tame?

Tags: biting, bonding, mice

So I just got this mouse exactly one week ago today. A couple days ago after the 3-4 day period of course I started the bonding and taming process. In this period I have successfully had him come willingly onto my hand and such, but he has bitten me twice already and I don't understand what is going on. Is there anything I can do? My reaction to him biting is to put him back in the cage and leaving him alone

Comment: Maybe that's what he wants right now. You have got to learn what he considers to be threatening behaviour, and adjust your own accordingly. Do not think that you can tickle his tummy on the basis of a few day's acquaintance.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something to Mick's comment. When a mouse bites you, it either is playing, feels threatened, is scared, or wants to defend itself. So the best option is to let it crawl in your hand (Do NOT pick it up by its tail or anywhere) and just hold it and try and tolerate the bite. It will eventually see your hand as not a threat and will not bite you anymore. If you pick it up yourself, then it will see your hand as a mouth of a predator and will just keep on biting you.